# Should I use the C or C++ implementation for returning a maximum size of a variable type?

Tags: c++, c, standards, char, limits

From a standards standpoint, should I use the following from the C++ `<limits>` header?

`UCHAR_MAX` which is the c implementation or
`std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()` which is the C++ implementation.

The result is equivalent between the two versions but should I choose an implementation based on some standard or on readability and portability in this case. Note this implementation must be cross-platform compatible. I am writing C++ code.

Comment: likely if you're programming in C++, you use C++ typical idioms, if in C, C typical idioms; afaik UCHAR_MAX is in <climits> from C++ (limits.h from C), so you should stick to <limits> where you can use std::numeric_limits ... which is more C++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the code to be able to compile as C, then you pretty much need to use `<limits.h>`. If you're writing C++, it's probably better to use the C++ `<limits>` header instead. The latter lets you write code that will work in templates that can't really be duplicated with the C header:

```
template <class T>
class mytemplate { 
    T x;
    void somefunc() { x = std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); } // or whatever...
};
```

Comment: Did you mean `static T`? This won't work pre-C++0x due to function calls not being allowed in constant expressions.

Comment: @Georg:Not really -- I just didn't bother to put the code into a function where it really belongs.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using C, `std::numeric_limits` obviously isn't available.

In C++ it depends on what you want to do - `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is not a constant expression with the current C++ standard.
In these cases an alternative to the C-ish macros would be to use something like Boost.Integers [integer traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/traits.html) `const_min`/`const_max` which also works in templated contexts.

Comment: According to Boost.integers const_max is equivalent to std::numeric_limits<T>::max().

Comment: @Elpez: Equivalent regarding their value, yes. But they are not functions, they are `static const` integrals, which means they can be used with e.g. `case` or to initialize `static const` integral members.

Answer (score 0):

Know what language you're writing in, and write in that language.  If you're writing C++, use the standard C++ ways of doing things.

Standard C++ is normally cross-platform compatible (there are exceptions, like `export`, but `export` is being removed from the C++ Standard anyway).  It's usually more readable to stick with C++ constructs than to switch between C and C++ constructs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use <limits> to stay consistant.

On the windows platform, if you include <windows.h>, you might also want to

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

to avoid a name conflict with min and max.

Comment: I like to avoid `<windows.h>` due to cross-compatibility issues